# length of vector in function of parameter and fill with sequence in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector

I would like to create a vector V and W with a length in function of parameter G. The job is related to matrix. Here my code for G=2:

```
  ncol <- 13
  G <- 2
  m <- matrix(, nrow = ncol, ncol = ncol)
  l <- matrix(1:(G*G), nrow = G, ncol = G)
  N <- ncol-(G)

  for (i in (0:(N))) {
    for(j in (0:(N))){
      V <- c(i+1, i+2)
      W <- c(j+1, j+2)
      m[V, W] <- l
    }
  }
```

For this example the length of V and W is 2. If I change G=3 I would like to have:

```
  V <- c(i+1, i+2, i+3)
  W <- c(j+1, j+2, j+3)
```

For G=4:

```
  V <- c(i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4)
  W <- c(j+1, j+2, j+3, j+4)
```

How to do create V and W to have the length in function of G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `seq` or `:` to generate sequence.

```
for (i in (0:(N))) {
   for(j in (0:(N))){
     V <- seq(i+1, i+G)
     #V <- (i+1):(i+G)
     W <- seq(j+1, j+G)
     #W <- (j+1):(j+G)
     m[V, W] <- l
    }
}
```